# How to filterOpt for not inSet?

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0

how can I filter on not inSet with the filterOpt? I want to remove all rows where item name is in the notBe set.

```scala
case class TableFilter(mustBe: Option[Set[String]], notBe: Option[Set[String]])

val q = items
    .filterOpt(filter.mustBe){ case (item, mustBe) => item.name inSet(mustBe) }
    .filterOpt(filter.notBe){ case (item, notBe) => item.name inSet(notBe) }
    .result
```

thank you very much,
ido